# Merge array items into string

Tags: php, arrays, string

How do I merge all the array items into a single string?

Comment: Do you want you array items to be comma seperated?...if so you can $finalarr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2) and do an implode(",", $finalarr) hope this helps

Comment: have a look at [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: i did array_merge because i misunderstood you question....when you said merge all array. but implode is certainly your answer..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the [`implode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

For example:

```
$fruits = array('apples', 'pears', 'bananas');
echo implode(',', $fruits);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this from the PHP manual (*[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)*):

```
<?php
    $array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

    echo $comma_separated; // lastname, email, and phone

    // Empty string when using an empty array:
    var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to just concatenate all of strings in the array, then you should look at [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 4):

```
$array1 = array(
    "one",
    "two",
)
$array2 = array(
    "three",
    "four",
)
$finalarr = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$finalarr = implode(",", $finalarr);
```

will produce this one,two,three,four

Answer (score 3):

You can use [join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php). It's an alias for [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), and in my opinion more readable:

```
$fruits = array('apples', 'pears', 'bananas');
echo join(',', $fruits);
```

Comment: `join` might be more readable, but `implode` is certainly more exciting.

Answer (score 1):

```
join(" -- ", Array("a", "b")) == "a -- b"
```

actually join is an alias for the implode function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge the string representation of a group of objects into a single string, you can use implode on an array of those objects. The objects' classes just have to have the `__toString()` magic method defined.

```
class myClass {

  protected $name;
  protected $value;
  public function __construct($name,$value) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->value = $value;
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return $this->name . '/' . $this->value;
  }
}

$obj1 = new myClass('one',1);
$obj2 = new myClass('two',2);

$obj_array = array($obj1, $obj2);

$string_of_all_objects = implode('|',$obj_array);

echo $string_of_all_objects; // 'one/1|two/2'
```

I found that trick useful to quickly get a string representation of a group of objects for display on a webpage. No need to loop through the object array with `foreach` and using `echo $obj->get('name')`.

EDIT: And here's and example with a "collection" class. I have 2 outputs (echos) at the end. The 2nd one should work, but I'm not sure about the 1st.

```
class myCollectionClass implements IteratorAggregate {
  protected $objects = array();

  public function __construct() {};
  public function add(myClass $object) {
    $this->objects[] = $object;
    return $this; // fluid
  }
  public function getIterator() { // for the interface
    return new ArrayIterator($this->objects);
  }
  public function __toString() {
    return implode($this->objects);
  }
}
$my_collection = new myCollectionClass();
$my_collection->add($obj1)->add($obj2); // add both myClass objects to the collection. can do in one line because fluid

//echo implode('|',$my_collection); // Comment out myCollectionClass's __toString method to test this. does it work? I'm not sure. But the next line will work thanks to myCollectionClass' __toString, which itself uses myClass's __toString

echo $my_collection; // same output as previous block before EDIT.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

$string .= $value .' ';

}
```

Comment: slow ... and what does "string" mean? and why extra space at the end of resulting string?

Comment: error, changed - fixed. how does implode work, and i dont mean the arguments. I'm refering to the function itself. please tell me.

Comment: implode will still iterate through the array.

Comment: @cocacola09 - Use a built-in function whenever possible, why re-invent the wheel. Keep code short ;-)

Comment: I fully admit implode is better solution but his response was that its slow. which is completely wrong. so I was correcting him. I fully admit implode is better for organisation of code.

Comment: +1 This does everything the question asks for in a good way. The coincidence that there is a more optimal way does not make this answer unhelpful.

Comment: Actually this does NOT do what the question asks. As Kamil Szot mentions, there is an extra space at the end of the last value. You would have to do `trim($string)` afterwards to get the same result. Not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array= array( "Alfred Hitchcock", "Stanley Kubrick", "Martin Scorsese", "Fritz Lang" );
$string="";

foreach ( $tempas $array) {
  $string=$string.",".$temp;
}
```

Comment: +1 This does everything the question asks for in a good way.  The coincidence that there is a more optimal way does not make this answer unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

For Multi Array such as:

```
 $multi_arrays = array(
            0 => array('model' => 'Product 1'),
            1 => array('model' => 'Product 2'),
            2 => array('model' => 'Product 3'),
            3 => array('model' => 'Product 4'));

 $pattern = array('/\[/', '/\]/', '/{"model":/', '/}/', '/\"/');

 $str_models = preg_replace($pattern, '', json_encode( $multi_arrays));
```

The result will be:

**Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, Product 4**

You can change pattern for get any result you want!