# Optimize PHP code (concatenating words with a comma, removing last comma)

Tags: php, string

I've used this method almost always to get "Word1, Word2, Word3" from an array('Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3')

Is it the shortest or acceptable method? Any better solution?

```
$sentence = '';
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $sentence .= $word . ", ";
}
$final_sentence = substr($sentence, 0, -2);

echo $final_sentence; //outputs contents of $words array separated by ,
```

Comment: It's really scary how close in timing those 3 answers were, even if one did originally contain a typo (which has since been fixed).

Comment: lol, you have rebuild `implode()` +1 for that

Comment: Wow!, this is brilliant!.. I'm embarrassed I've been overlooking `implode()` for so long!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge array items into string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626732/merge-array-items-into-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$sentence = implode(', ', $words);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$final_sentence = implode(", ", $words);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$final_sentence = implode(', ',$words)
```

Comment: Semicolon fairy strikes again. ;)

Comment: <blush color="brightRed">Too much time spent on javascript recently</blush>