# Split Array Items with a Character

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I have an array with a few items in it (e.g. item1, item2, item3) and I want to split each item with a "|", so it will look like this at the end: item1|item2|item3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge array items into string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626732/merge-array-items-into-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [**`implode()`**](https://www.php.net/implode) function :

```
$arr = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$str = implode('|', $arr);
var_dump($str);
```

Will get you :

```
string 'item1|item2|item3' (length=17)
```

---

As a sidenote : what you are doing here is **joining** *([`join()`](http://fr.php.net/join) is actually an alias of `implode()`)*, and not **splitting**.

Splitting would be the opposite operation, and would be done, in PHP, using the [**`explode()`**](http://fr.php.net/explode) function :

```
$arr = explode('|', 'item1|item2|item3');
var_dump($arr);
```

would get you :

```
array
  0 => string 'item1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'item2' (length=5)
  2 => string 'item3' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `implode('|', $array);`

Answer (score 1):

That looks like joining and not splitting.

You can use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function as:

```
$str = implode('|',$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["item1", "item2", "item3" ]

print "|".join( a )
```

Prints out item1|item2|item3

Comment: This looks a bit like Javascript *(or something else ? python ?)* -- but this question is tagged `php`