# Turning an array into one long string

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, string-concatenation

If I have an array in php that contains a simple list e.g:

```
$colors = $array();
$colors = 'black', 'white', 'blue', 'red';
```

Is there a function or a way to loop through the array to make a variable equal a STRING of the results?
For example:

```
$theseColors = 'black, white, blue, red';
```

Cheers!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Please do some research before asking superfluous duplicates or questions that are easily answerable by looking at the PHP Manual. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge array items into string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626732/merge-array-items-into-string)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$colors = $array(); $colors = 'black', 'white', 'blue', 'red';
```

won't work. it's an error here. this is correct:

```
$colors = array(); $colors = array('black', 'white', 'blue', 'red');
```

and then

```
$theseColours  = implode(", ", $colors);
```

Comment: @stereofrog, ok, made an edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$theseColors  = implode(', ',$colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Join / implode...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$theseColors = implode(', ', $colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($color as $colors) {
    $theseColours = $theseColours . $color;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to invent a bycicle. and your code is wrong.