# How to insert all index elements of one array to one single element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array that has values of `arr1 = [1,2,3]` and what I want to do is that `1,2,3` will store to another array with single index just like this `arr 2 = [123]` because this `arr 2` will the one that I will store to the database.

my code is this

```
if($bul == "true"){
            while ($ai < count($sentencearr)){
                for($i = 0; $i<count($alpha); $i++){
                    if($sentencearr[$ai] == $alpha[$i]){
                        $answer[$ai] = $choicearray[$i];
                        $ia = count($alpha) + 1;
                    }else if($sentencearr[$ai] == $alphaup[$i]){
                        $answer[$ai] = $choicearrayup[$i];
                        $ia = count($alpha)+1;
                    }
                }
                $insert_arry = join($answer[$ai]);
                $sql = "insert into message(msg, name) values ('$insert_arry[$ai]', '$name')";
                $result=$conn->query($sql);
                header("Location:home.php");
                $ai++;
            }
```

Comment: If you store it like that, then it's a string? Or do you mean one array with one item that is a string of all items in arr1 combined without delimiter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge array items into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626732/merge-array-items-into-string). Perhaps not a perfect match, but `$arr2[] = implode()` is close enough to make it duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create a String from an Array you could simply use `implode`. Implode allows you to separate your array by any character you define. In your case you don't want to seperate it so you can leave it away. As a last step you will need to put the string back intro an array.

This looks like this:

```php
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [ implode($arr1) ];
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: @Ana That's what the code above does. But in order to achieve this, you could also just create a multidimensional array: `$arr2 = array( 'index-1' => $arr1 )`

Comment: but how I will do that inside the looping? my code is like this

Comment: $exam = [implode($answer[$ai])];
     $ai++;
    }
    $sql = "insert into message(msg, name) values ('$exam', '$name')";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
     header("Location:home.php");

Comment: Where is the loop? The above code works for what you asked for. Sry I can't help you with this one. Please update your question with all the code which is mandatory to understand the problem. THX.

Comment: okay thanks I already edit it